# Why should I mine Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-theory

Please teach me why I should mine bitcoins, aswell as how please so I can learn.

Please, I really want to mine!

Answer (score 0):

Buy [an ASIC](https://shop.bitmain.com/product/detail?pid=00020180404095933774DvU29DS10644). In this age, it's not profitable to mine using usual computers. These specialized computers are used for mining.